# Installing Ubuntu on Mac Pro black cylinder fails

Tags: mac

I just got the new Mac Pro black cylinder with AMD D700 GPU and I'm not able to finalize the Ubuntu install. I followed the steps from your instructions "How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X" from here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

And all of that goes well, I boot up and see the boot menu, then I select option 1) and I get the following:

kernel path: /casper/vmlinuz | ramdisc path: /casper/initrd.lz
boot parameters:

Loading Linux kernel...done
Loading initial RAM disc...done
Attempting to boot the Linux distribution now...
error: no suitable video mode found.
Booting in blind mode

Then after a few seconds the Mac reboots itself and that's the end of it.
Have you seen this error before? Is it the GPU hardware drivers that aren't compatible?

I used ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso

Thanks a lot,
Alejandro

Comment: Are you using EFI/UEFI bootloaders? This may help: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=291f36325f9f252bd76ef5f603995f37e453fc60

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I'm not very familiar with booting issues but I understand your questions and I read your provided link.

The installer is booting directly from the USB key created using your guide "How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X". I don't know what's using to boot, either EFI/UEFI or whatever else. I also have rEFInd installed but the error above comes from booting directly from the USB key, meaning that it doesn't even go into rEFInd. After the install fails then it reboots and goes into rEFInd where I see the same USB key.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that happened to me using a MSI, since the Mac pro black is VERY new I assume you may need to wait a few months before real docs or guides are released.

Comment: Is there a way to bring this to the attention of the Ubuntu people so a solution can be expedited?

Thank you for your help,
Alejandro

Answer (score 1):

I have documented the instructions to install Ubuntu on the Mac Pro Cylinder (Late 2013) here: [Mac Pro Cylinder Ubuntu Install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacPro)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @user282366 Any idea how I/we can get dual monitors to work?

Comment: I got a black screen when starting Ubuntu 14.04 lightdm on MacPro 2013. Which GPU driver should we use for D700?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. As a pointer not an answer I saw there is a special ISO for Macs with the new 14.04 release:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

I've not been able to get any further with that on the black cylinder, but perhaps you'll have better luck. I'd love to find out how to run ubuntu on my mac pro too!